# Are call-by-value and pass-by-value synonymous?

Tags: c#, calling-convention, evaluation-strategy

I always thought *call-by-value* and *pass-by-value* were synonymous.  However, I recently heard someone refer to them as if they were different.  Are they the same thing?

I'm also talking about their corresponding *by-reference* terms too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are synomynous.

"call" means the method, and "pass" means an(the) argument(s).

Example:

1. argument #1 was passed by value/reference.
2. the arguments were passed by value.
3. the method is used in a call by value context.

Comment: Pointing out that "call" refers to the method and "pass" refers to the argument makes it all makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

"Someone," is wrong. Check out the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) which directly answers your question. You can point that certain "someone" at this article, as well:

> Call-by-value evaluation (also
>   referred to as pass-by-value) is the
>   most common evaluation strategy, ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes those terms are synonyms as I understand them.

However, I think you are asking the wrong audience. If your colleague regards them as different, then you and they have a mismatch of understanding. Whether or not I think they are the same is irrelevant, what counts is what your colleague actually means.

Comment: True, but I don't know how to reach the fellow.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

They are synonymous. The term *call-by-value* means exactly the same as *pass-by-value*.

However, I prefer the *pass-by-value* form, as it's the parameter that is passed that it refers to. A call can have parameters that are passed by value as well as parameters passed by reference.

Example:

```
public void Something(string name, int count, ref string target, ref int result)
```

The first parameter is a reference passed by value, the second is a value passed by value, the third is a reference passed by reference, and the fourth is a value passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

I've always considered them synonymous, but when I think about it, perhaps they're trying to differentiate between calling a method directly and calling a method through a reference (i.e. a delegate).  That is, given this:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate();

class MyClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

MyClass thing = new MyClass();
```

Are they trying to say that if you write:

```
thing.DoSomething();
```

Then it's a "call by value", but if you write:

```
MyDelegate dlgt = thing.DoSomething;
dlgt();  // calls thing.DoSomething through the delegate reference
```

then it's a "call by reference?"